# Finding constrained optima of $f(x,y) = x^3 - y^3 -x$

Tags: lagrange-multiplier

For a function $$f(x,y) = x^3 - y^3 -x$$, the minimum and maximum under the constraint $$x^2 + y^2 =1 $$

is searched.

So as usual, my approach is to set up the Lagrangian and the FOC:

$$ L(x,y, \lambda) = x^3 - y^3 -x + \lambda(x^2 + y^2 -1)$$
$$ \frac{\delta L}{\delta x} = 3 x^2-1+ 2\lambda x = 0 $$
$$ \frac{\delta L}{\delta y} = -3 y^2+ 2\lambda y = 0 $$
$$x^2 + y^2 - 1 = 0 $$

That, however, appears to be fairly complicated to solve, as both substituting $y=\sqrt{1-x^2}$ and $x=\sqrt{1-y^2}$ ends up in a pretty messy equation.
Thus, I wonder, am I on the right path at all?

Given past assignments, I observed a tendency of 'nice' solutions, but the current path doesn't seem nice at all, which is why I would be grateful for some input. Thanks!

Comment: If you _have_ to use Lagrange multipliers, what I recommend is solving the equations containing $\lambda$ for $\lambda$, set the two $\lambda$'s equal to each other, then you will have two equations in $x$ in $y$.  In this kind of problem you don't really care about the value of $\lambda$.  Of course, when you eliminate $\lambda$ you divide by $x$ and $y$ so you will have to do the $x=0$ and $y=0$ cases separately.

Answer (score 1):

Idea: Substitute $x$ by $\cos \varphi$ and $y$ by $\sin \varphi$ for $\varphi \in [0,\pi/2)$ and see if the objective function can be put in a nice form using trigonometric identities. The constraint is satisfied.

Comment: I agree with the answer above.  Although this is a standard Lagrange multiplier problem, it is probably a lot easier to solve using the trig approach if you have the option.

Answer (score 0):

it is not difficult to solve the $x,y$.

first :$y=0$ case, $x^2=1$, you get $2$ pair $(x,y)$

second: $y \not=0$, $x\not=0$, then $y=\dfrac{1}{3x}-2x$, you put in $x^2+y^2=1$, you will have something like $ax^4+bx^2+c=0$, so you have $4$ pair $(x,y)$, some may not real numbers.

last step you should know what to do with these $(x,y)$.